# Keep GeckoFX print window on top

Tags: c#, printing, geckofx

I have a `C#` application with `GeckoFX` Web Browser than runs in fullscreen mode and users can't open any other apps on the PC. In my application when user clicks on web pages "Print" button and print window pops out, before the user can choose printer and press "Print", if my web browser navigates to some other link, print window is left behind the main window.

`Alt+Tab` combination is disabled in my application, thus I'm looking for some other solutions on how to keep the print window on top of the main app window, even when web browser navigates to other links.

Answer (score 1):

I am running a C# application my self with GeckoFX ( xulrunner: v33 ). Application is running on Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10

I have Problems from time to time with Windows 7 and Windows 8, when I want to print as well.

Test case: Printing to USB-Printer and/or Network-Printer. After 5th/10th/20th print, I get an error message that popups up: "Printer Error". Very intermittently.

To make it work again: I have to shutdown the app and restart the app again.